# AngularJS templates render locally, but not in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, templates, heroku

I'm building an app with AngularJS & Rails 4, and am using Heroku to host the site.

I placed several templates under an assets/templates folder as haml files.

I created a haml initializer with `Rails.application.assets.register_engine '.haml', Tilt::HamlTemplate` and added the following line to my application.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'templates')
```

I did this based on other threads on stackOverflow.

This works great locally, but when trying to access the site after pushing to heroku it can't seem to locate the templates in the assets/templates directory. I am referencing my template URL as templateUrl: `./assets/cityOverview.html`

Specifically, my Heroku logs shows:

> 2014-02-10T05:17:25.042728+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/cityWelcome.html"):

What am I missing? should I move my templates to views?

Comment: try out this url and see whether this helps:- https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/95#issuecomment-27367210

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML templates on production may be appended with a hash! For instance, on development the file path will be `/assets/cityOverview.html` but on production the Rails asset pipeline will add a hash like this: `/assets/cityOverview-41ac8fc9a65390498a34680a9uc53951.html`

This means you can't specify the template name in your JS file as `"/assets/cityOverview.html"`. You can rename your js file to .js.erb and then write `"<%=asset_path '/assets/cityOverview.html'%>"`. This ensures that the filename will have the hash as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. I see that you join haml middleware to your application, but instead of using .haml templates you use .html templates
2. Use absolute pathes (SITE_PATH:port/assets/TEMPLATE_NAME)